# Erro 406 usando Rest Delphi components "TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST" para enviar XML

Tags: delphi, xml, rest, post, token

O RESTResponse.StatusCode retorna sempre 406

o token esta Correto.

Alguém tem ideia o que está errado?

```
ReSTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(Application);
RESTResponse  := TRESTResponse.Create(Application);
RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
// ... BIND RESTClient AND REST Response TO REST Request

OAuth2_PMF:= TOAuth2Authenticator.Create(Application);
OAuth2_PMF.AuthorizationEndpoint := sLinkEmitir;
OAuth2_PMF.RedirectionEndpoint := sLinkEmitir;

RESTRequest.ResetToDefaults;
RESTClient.ResetToDefaults;
RESTResponse.ResetToDefaults;

OAuth2_PMF.AccessToken := pAnsichar( pToken);

RESTRequest.Client      := RESTClient;
RESTRequest.Response    := RESTResponse;

RESTClient.BaseURL :=   'https://nfps-e.pmf.sc.gov.br/api/v1/processamento/notas/processa'; 

//RESTClient.Authenticator := nil;
RESTClient.Authenticator :=  OAuth2_PMF;

RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

LDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
LDocument.LoadFromFile( pAnsichar( pArquivoXML)); { File should exist.     }

RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('Authorization', ' Bearer ' + OAuth2_PMF.AccessToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
//RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('Host', 'nfps-e.pmf.sc.gov.br', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
//RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('Content-Type', 'application/xml', TREstRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode], TRESTContentType.ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

RESTRequest.AddBody(LDocument.XML.Text ,  ctTEXT_XML );
RESTRequest.Accept := 'text/xml';
showmessage('ANTES EXECUTE');
RESTRequest.Execute;
showmessage('depois EXECUTE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa tudo bem ? pelo que percebi, você poderia mudar.

1 - Não precisa: RESTResponse  := TRESTResponse.Create(Application);

2 - Esse espaço ' Bearer ' é suspeito...

3 - No mais o status code 406 é quando a requisição não é aceita(406 Not
Acceptable)   tenta verificar a documentação com endpoint.

4 -  Tente fazer o request usando insominia ou postman.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).